# Displaying duplicate records

Tags: perl

I've a code as below to parse a text file. Display all words after "Enter:" keyword on all lines of the text file. I'm getting displayed all words after "Enter:" keyword, but i wan't duplicated should not be repeated but its repeating. Please guide me as to wht is wrong in my code.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
$infile  "xyz.txt";
open (FILE, $infile) or die ("can't open file:$!");
if(FILE =~ /ENTER/ ){
    @functions = substr($infile, index($infile, 'Enter:'));
    @functions =~/@functions//;
    %seen=();
    @unique = grep { ! $seen{$_} ++ } @array;
    while (@unique != ''){
        print '@unique\n';
    }
}
close (FILE);
```

Comment: You may want to add some line breaks to your code.  ;)

Comment: How does that work with the strict pragma on?

Comment: oh ok. so what needs to be modified to work?

Comment: Did you really copy/paste your real code?

Comment: almost everything needs to be modified...

Comment: i'm new to perl...what i need is i need a code for removing the duplicates in each line after the keyword "Enter:".

Comment: I'd look into the [Learning Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018452.do) book. You can't learn Perl with a SO question.

Comment: @M42 - I don't want to edit your edit of the question, but isn't the subject of the question wrong? Additionaly, there is a typo as well.

Comment: @stackoverflow: Feel free to edit the question. I've left it as it was posted, i've just formatted the code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do the job, it prints unique words found on each line that begins with the keyword `Enter:`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $infile = "xyz.txt";

# use 3 arg open with lexical file handler
open my $fh, '<', $infile or die "unable to open '$infile' for reading: $!";

# loop thru all lines
while(my $line = <$fh) {
    # remove linefeed;
    chomp($line);
    # if the line begins with "Enter:"
    # remove the keyword "Enter:"
    if ($line =~ s/^Enter:\s+//) {
        # split the line on whitespaces
        # and populate the array with all words found
        my @words = split(/\s+/, $line);
        # create a hash where the keys are the words found
        my %seen = map { $_ => 1 }@words;
        # display unique words
        print "$_\t" for(keys %seen);
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, one problem is that your 'grep' only counts the occurrences of each word. I think you want to use 'map' so that '@unique' only contains the unique words from '@array'. Something like this:

```
@unique = map {
    if (exists($seen{$_})) {
        ();
    } else {
        $seen{$_}++; $_;
    }
 } @array;
```

Comment: Well, darn. Totally forgot about List::Util (and in the CORE, too!) Thanks for pointing that out.